# javascript disable second onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Delay = 10;//Seconds after them clicking the link, the gateway vanishes. 
    function setupgateway()
    {

        var Left = $(window).width() /2;
                Left = Left - $('#gatewaydiv').width()/2;

        var Top = $(window).height() /2;
        Top = Top - $('#gatewaydiv').height()/2;

        $('#gatewaydiv').css('top', Top+'px').css('left', Left+'px').css('display', 'inline');
        $('#gatewayDimmer').width($('html').width());
        $('#gatewayDimmer').height($('html').height());
        $('#gatewayDimmer').css({display:'block', position:'fixed'});
    }

    function removegateway()
    {
        $('#gatewaydiv').css('display', 'none');
        $('#gatewayDimmer').css('display','none');
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
                $('.my-link').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

        $('.offerlink').click(function()
        {
            setTimeout('removegateway()', Delay*10);
        });

        setupgateway();
                });
    });
</script
```

...a pop-up, if you will, that's called/triggered by clicking an image(s) and goes away after x amount of seconds a link in the pop-up is clicked. I need the image(s)(callers/triggers) to go where it's(they're) linked to once clicked again, not call the javascript. What do I have to do to disable the javascript after the first click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.click()`:

```
$('.my-link').one('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.offerlink').click(function()
    {
        setTimeout(removegateway, Delay*10);
    });

    setupgateway();
});
```

`.one()` is like `.click()`, but is run only once and is then unbound.

Comment: thanks, but once[those special images] are clicked, now they dont bring up the javascript at all

Comment: You're missing the 'click' event.  `.one('click', fn)`

Comment: Yeah, right, now you're just making stuff u—oh hey, there really is a `one` that loads an event to run...once.  +1.  Do they have a some sort of `num` function that lets you run an event `N` times?

Comment: Sorry, I lost the first `click` in your formatting. Try the above code.

Comment: The `.one()` probably belongs on the `$('.offerlink')` instead of the `$('.my-link')`, but the OP really hasn't made the behavior terribly clear...

Comment: i see your edit now matt, thanks that works, and thanks J-man

Comment: And just a general comment: don't mix up `one()` and `on()` - not that _I've_ ever done that of course, no, it um...happened to a friend of mine, yeah, um...that's my story and I'm sticking to it...

Answer (score 0):

Put the code for binding the click in a function so that you can reuse it. Unbind the click when you show the gateway, and rebind it when you remove the gateway.

Note: The time unit for `setTimeout` is milliseconds, so `Delay*10` would give you 0.1 seconds, not 10 seconds.

```
function bindLink() {
  $('.my-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.offerlink').click(function() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        removegateway();
        bindLink();
      }, Delay * 1000);
    });

    setupgateway();
    $('.my-link').unbind('click');
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  bindLink();
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the info, and will use it if for whatever reason the above answer stops working. Oh, and thanks for the time explanation; I'm aware of that.